# How to set bold and center text by default using ckeditor5

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor5

I'm using ckeditor5 and I'm trying to set the editor by default to be bold and center.
So that the user starts writing, the text will be bold and center.

I saw similar questions asked, but none of the answers worked as expected,
I tried to use `text-align: center` on the editor element, and also on the parent element, but it didn't work (I also used `!important`)

```js
ClassicEditor
.create(document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
  // Editor configuration.
})
.catch( error => {
    console.error( error );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/40.2.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>

<div style="text-align: center !important; font-weight: bold !important">
    <textarea id="editor" style="text-align: center !important; font-weight: bold !important"></textarea>
</div>
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the method to do it.

You need to use the function `execute()`

Ckeditor5 documentation: [here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/text-alignment.html#common-api).

Demo code:

```js
ClassicEditor
.create(document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
    // Editor configuration.
}).then(editor => {
    editor.execute('bold');
    editor.execute('heading', { value: 'heading2' });
    //  Code for text alignment (not included in classic editor)
    //  editor.execute('alignment', { value: 'center'});
})
.catch( error => {
    console.error( error );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/40.2.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>

<textarea id="editor"></textarea>
```